# What hebrew letter is this?

Tags: hebrew

So I was searching around for some hebrew texts and I stumbled upon this

[image: From the seals of Solomon]

I can cleary make out the letters:
 Mem, Yud, Ghet, Tet

and this is where it gets tricky, the circled letter is a mystery for me, I thought of it being Lamed but it's too odd with the line going through underneath it..

Does anyone know what we're dealing with?

Thanks!

C.C.

Edit: can't really wrap my head around the fact that the question was centered around linguistics.. but it somehow isn't. 
What sort of StackExchange should this be asked on?

Comment: Probably worth getting in the habit of reading right to left, even if just naming letters in a word :)

Comment: (Sometimes unfortunately,) this site has the specific policy of not allowing questions for "identification of or translation of specific samples of text", because the site would otherwise get flooded by such requests. See other recent questions here (or the [help/on-topic]) for what questions are welcomed here. There is [a proposal](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/113173/semitic-languages?referrer=E7543yclX-MBmqgt1wfCkA2) to create a Stack Exchange site for Semitic languages. You can support it by following it and voting for example questions, and hopefully it can be launched.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying! does that mean that I should delete this?

Comment: I'm not sure what the guidelines are on this site, but it won't do much harm — do as you like unless anybody tells you otherwise :-)

Comment: My comment probably belongs to the meta, but if Linguistics.SE wants to graduate out of beta ever, we should lower our noses down a few degrees. Look at Physics.SE, where much more layman questions are answered  (without upvoting tho). Most questions allowed here are either (1) too narrow and technical to be even allowed on other SE forums, bar SO, or (2) must be answered "nobody agrees but one theory is...". My impression this SE is just too academic.This would be a perfectly valid question on an average SE site, and I see such normal questions downvoted to naught and closed daily.

Comment: This is not an identification of sample of text, but of a single sign. Some graphemes are and have historically underwent so much variation, so you need to be an expert to identify it, Take my proud upvote.

Comment: Exactly my thought! I just couldn't figure out what letter it was. I wasn't asking for the translation of an entire scripture but just a single letter..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a ב (beth). The thing above it that made you think of a lamed is a cholem (the vowel sign), and it has a dagesh in the middle. This is a masculine plural participle of the root בטח "to trust", i.e. "those who trust" (if used as a noun). This word is for instance used in [Jeremiah 46:25](https://www.blueletterbible.org/kjv/jer/46/1/t_conc_791025):

> אָמַר יְהוָה צְבָאֹות אֱלֹהֵי יִשְׂרָאֵל הִנְנִי פֹוקֵד אֶל־אָמֹון מִנֹּא וְעַל־פַּרְעֹה וְעַל־מִצְרַיִם וְעַל־אֱלֹהֶיהָ וְעַל־מְלָכֶיהָ וְעַל־פַּרְעֹה וְעַל **הַבֹּטְחִים** בֹּֽו
>   The LORD of hosts, the God of Israel, said: “Behold, I am bringing punishment upon Amon of Thebes, and Pharaoh and Egypt and her gods and her kings, upon Pharaoh and **those who trust** in him. (ESV)